# Equality comparison PHP

Tags: php, laravel

I'm doing this comparison below: `$deviceKey == 'mobile' or $deviceKey == 'desktop'`

```
    public function syncPublisherIds (string $publisherId, Request $request):array
    {
        file_put_contents('/var/log/php/burner.log', json_encode($request->getContent()) . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);

        $idSyncConfig = json_decode($request->getContent());
        $idSyncResponseObject = new \stdClass();

        foreach($idSyncConfig as $deviceKey => $deviceValue) {
            // file_put_contents('/var/log/php/burner.log', json_encode(gettype($deviceKey)) . '   '. json_encode($deviceValue) . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
            // $deviceKey = json_encode($deviceKey);

            // add device type to object
            if ($deviceKey == 'mobile' or $deviceKey == 'desktop') {
                $idSyncResponseObject[$deviceKey] = new \stdClass();
            } else {
                throw ((new BadRequestException("Platforms must be of type 'mobile' or 'desktop', you sent type of: $deviceKey"))->errorize());
            }

        }
    }
```

For some reason it hits the else statement when they are seemingly the same:
`"Platforms must be of type 'mobile' or 'desktop', you sent type of: \"mobile\""`

This is a Laravel endpoint.

Comment: What does `$deviceKey` and `$deviceValue` return? Cannot do much without an idea of what is returned from the request.

Comment: @kimhallberg $deviceKey is the key of a json object. $deviceValue is a string that returns ‘mobile’ or ‘desktop’.

Comment: Then you're checking the wrong thing if `$deviceValue` returns the string, update your comparison to check against `$deviceValue` instead of `$deviceKey`.

Comment: I misspoke. $deviceKey is a JSON key AND the value of the key is either ‘desktop’ or ‘mobile’

Comment: Do you have any space / special characters before or after the string "mobile" ?

Comment: The second to last line above is exactly how it comes through

Comment: If that what's returned `"Platforms must be..."` then your need to parse out what you wanna check for. The comparison is searching for an **equal** comparison, i.e. is `"mobile" == "mobile"`, that will never match with `"Platforms must be..." == "mobile"`.

Comment: Shouldn't the logical operator be `||` instead of `or`?

Comment: try dumping the `$request->getContent();` rightbafter logging and confirm whether it is a json string or an array. I can see `json_encode()` and `json_decode()` on`$request->getContent();` on consecutive lines.

Comment: @schoenbl did you get a chance to try out my suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

function testForLuke(string $requestContent): void
{
  $idSyncConfig = json_decode(stripslashes($requestContent));

  //print_r([$requestContent, $idSyncConfig]);
  foreach ($idSyncConfig as $deviceKey => $deviceValue) {
    //print_r([$deviceKey, $deviceValue]);

    if ($deviceKey === 'mobile' || $deviceKey === 'desktop') {
      echo "great success with deviceKey of '${deviceKey}'!\n";
    } else {
      echo "error condition throw exception\n";
    }
  }
}

testForLuke('{ "mobile": { "id": 1 } }');
testForLuke('{ "desktop": { "id": 1 } }');
testForLuke('{ "derptop": { "id": 1 } }');
testForLuke("{ \"mobile\": { \"id\": 1 } }");
testForLuke("{ \"desktop\": { \"id\": 1 } }");
```

For me yields:

```
great success with deviceKey of 'mobile'!
great success with deviceKey of 'desktop'!
error condition throw exception
great success with deviceKey of 'mobile'!
great success with deviceKey of 'desktop'!
```

The code seems to be working already, but is highly dependent on the structure of the provided JSON, so depending on the structure of the request you may still have issues, let us know.

**Edit:** After re-looking, it seems like you've got backslashes in your JSON request. Are you encoding it yourself? If so you should use `json_encode($response, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);`

If you can't control how it is encoded for whatever you reason, you could consider using:

```
$idSyncConfig = json_decode(stripslashes($requestContent));
```